# Read contents of posted file and pass to thread

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Here's my method header:

```
private Hashtable uploadItemResource(Hashtable htRequest, 
        int userId, HttpPostedFile file, SessionData sessionData) {
```

The file object is a file that's been posted from my website.  I'm trying to send this file to AWS in another thread

```
PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
titledRequest
    //other options left out
    .WithInputStream(file.InputStream);
```

And then I run `s3Client.PutObject(titledRequest);` in a thread.

The problem is that I'm getting this exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was
>   canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all
>   bytes are written.     at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean
>   aborting)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I assume this is because the file object is going out of scope, and is trying to dispose while the AWS call is still trying to read it.

What's the best way to fix this?  What's the best way to dump out the contents of the file ahead of time, and pass *that* to AWS?

Comment: Why not make a copy of the `file.InputStream` and use *that* in your thread?  I may be missing something :)

Comment: @Eben - right - I'm a stream IO ignoramus, my somewhat high rep notwithstanding.  What's the best way to make a copy of it??

Comment: *lol* Is there really a *best* way?

Comment: @Eben Well `byte[] buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength]; file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);` which gets passed to a memoryStream seems to work - is there any reason that might be a bad idea?

Comment: As you are probably thinking it may become an issue for larger files since it is duplicating the stream for a while (or with many upload requests).  However, since I don't know AWS I don't know whether a file can be streamed from disk in chunks.

Comment: I too am experiencing the same issue.
Works in my local development version, could be some restrictions by hosting provider

Comment: @BabuJames - try adding a .WithTimeout method call to the request object.

Comment: @AdamRackis: The actual problem was the Request.InputStream was getting closed because I was returning from the action just after the thread becomes alive. I solved it by writing the file to a temporary location and then copying it to the amazon server.

I indeed had the Timeout which wasn't of any help